# How to build amorphous Al2O3 using the AIMD method implemented in VASP?

Tags: vasp, molecular-dynamics, amorphous-materials, aimd

I want to build amorphous $\ce{Al_2O_3}$ with the AIMD (ab initio molecular dynamics) method implemented in VASP.
I'm thinking of this process in three steps:

1. Build initial supercell
2. Melt
3. Quench

I have questions about all these steps, but here I will just address the first.

### Supercell size

The conventional cell of $\ce{Al_2O_3}$ (taken from [the materials project website](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-755483/#)) contains 15 atoms, as shown in the following figure.

[image: Al2O3 conventional cell]

To do AIMD calculations, we must have enough atoms in the simulated cell. This means that I need to build a supercell. For the current system, is a $3 \times 3 \times 1$ (135 atoms) supercell OK? To obtain a reasonable amorphous structure, **how big should the melt supercell be?**

Comment: +1. But I just changed the title slightly. There's a few disadvantages of using MathJax in titles, such as disqualifying the question from appearing on the Hot Network Questions list: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/190/5

Comment: How "amorphous" your structure is will depend on the cell size.  Do you intend to make a surface out of it?  I think this question is answerable as is, but some slightly more detailed goals might help.  If you need a surface, it may affect things differently.

Comment: @TristanMaxson:https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259368340_Amorphous_Fe2O3_as_a_High-Capacity_High-rate_and_Long-Life_Anode_Material_for_Lithium_Ion_Batteries  Please take a look at this paper. The amorphous Fe2O3 is built from AIMD.

Comment: I made some edits to the question to bump it back up, but part of the reason it may not be getting answers is it's fairly broad. It would probably work better as 3 separate questions that link to each other.

Comment: @Tyberius Thanks.

Comment: I've trimmed the post down to one question. The text of the other two should still be retrievable from the edit history.

Comment: Have you figured this out now Jack? Please give us an update!

Comment: @NikeDattani Unfortunately, nope.

Comment: Just an idea: have you considered using reversed Monte Carlo to make amorphous structures?